# File is not copying into the path

Tags: java, file, directory

I am trying to copy file to a path however after the process complete file doesn't exist in the destination path. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Following are my code:

```
String srcPath; 

String DesPath;

String src1 = srcPath;

             String des = DesPath;

             File dir = new File(src1);

             File[] files = dir.listFiles();

             System.out.println(files[0].getPath());

             Path src = Paths.get(files[0].getPath());

             Path dst = Paths.get(des + files[0].getName());

Files.copy(src, dst, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: Print result of `des + files[0].getName()` and `dst`. Is that correct location for copy?

Comment: Change it to `Paths.get(des, files[0].getName());` You presumably don't have a directory separator between the directory and the filename.

Comment: The destination path directory exists? The 'des' string ends with a '/'?

Comment: Changing to Paths.get(des, files[0].getName()); is resolved this issue.